Which integer sequences are a must to learn for math students?
This question is a result of my contemplation on mathematics and recalling my own knowledge.
What are some most important integer sequences that a newbie in number theory proficient in high school math curriculum should by all means learn?
Some of my favorite choices (with links to OEIS on their names) are:

Prime Numbers, Semiprime Numbers, Twin Prime Numbers. A very fundamental sequence encouraging deep research.
Odd Numbers and Even Numbers. The first natural number dichotomy ever.
Fibonacci Sequence and Lucas Sequence. The Golden Ratio, and a lot to it.


Arithmetic and Geometric Sequence

I wonder what you might mean by "learning" the sequence of twin primes...

There are definitely sequences I have become familiar with through maths degrees - to the extent that I would recognise some of their early terms and that can be useful for conjecturing a pattern. The most obvious of these are squares, cubes, powers of some small numbers, Fibonacci, primes and the starts of the sequences of decimal digits of $\pi$, $e$ and some square roots. OEIS is an invaluable resource for figuring out a tricky unknown sequence.

Certainly someone who is proficient in high school math already knows about even and odd numbers? Also the focus on sequences seems misguided to me. You should definitely learn about the concepts of primes or modular arithmetic, say, and study  their properties. But whether you can extract some sequences from that should not be the main focus of these topics; indeed focusing on the sequence may distract from the actually interesting mathematics.

The catalan numbers are arguably more important than all but the prime numbers in the lists you mentioned.

Triangular numbers (and their appearance in Pascal's triangle).
